# 100% width of grand parent without position absolute

Tags: css

In the following html/css code:

```
<div class="blue">
    <div class="red">
        <div class="yellow">
            1
        </div>
        <div class="yellow">
            2
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

.blue   { background-color: blue;   height: 150px; width: 100px; margin: 100px; }
.red    { background-color: red;    height: 100px; width: 500px; margin-left: -50px; }
.yellow { background-color: yellow; height: 50px;  }
```

I need to give `.yellow` the same width as `.blue`, but without using fixed px (as `.blue` is responsive and can change it's width) and without using `position: absolute;` as the two yellow must not overlap.

Expected result: http://jsfiddle.net/kPg97/3/

This doesn't work as it uses fixed px:

```
.yellow { width: 100px; float: left; }
```

This doesn't work as the first `.yellow` isn't visible:

```
.yellow { position: absolute; width: 100%; left: 0px; }
```

Comment: Can you use Javascript/jQuery?

Comment: You say blue is responsive and red? have fixed width? and responsive how %? or max - min?

Comment: @intelis: I'd like to avoid it.

Comment: @Danko: red has fixed width. blue has 100% of viewport with 1100px max-width

Comment: can you tell me the fixed width for th red one? you may need a tricky calc tu do this

Comment: @Danko: in this example 500px (in real use case it's more but that shouldn't matter)

Answer (score 0):

Probably with `jquery`, you can do like this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var width = $(".blue").width();
    $(".yellow").width(width);
});
```

You can do without `jquery`, you may have understood though.

Please note a `display:inline;` and `float:left` were used. Hope they won't conflict with your interest.
**Jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/z2wcW/)**

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I want to do this using css only.